# How to endlessly and continuously instantiate a gameobject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation

The game consists of a player and a ground. Where the ground is a cube being instantiated relative to the cube before, either on its right or left. The player's goal is to swipe or move in the correct direction and to land on the ground(cube).

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugNaG.png)

However, I have only managed to instantiate a limited amount of cubes without having Unity crash as a result of an endless loop of instantiating cubes.

I have also tried to destroy a cube from the bottom when no longer in the camera view(using the `OnBecomeInvisible()` method) in order to be able to instantiate a cube at the top of the limited amount of cubes instantiated, as to give a feeling of endless gameplay, but as the camera follows the player, some cubes appear in the scene on either far left or right but as the camera gets centered once again they are no longer visible, which in turn destroys the cube before even the player lands on the cube or view it.

Would making the ground scroll, and when it drops below a certain Y value, it gets destroyed as it is out of the camera's view, work? I have tried it already but I feel like it is supposed to work.

Are there any other methods?

Comment: Given that you have limited RAM, unlimied objects do not work. | The struture I would use would be something approaching a Queue - a limited list of "active cubes". If you need more then the limit, the oldest cube would be dropped first to make room - everything else would just move up. Note that the build-in queue will likely not work, as it does not allow read access (to display) all the intermediate cubes.

Comment: Could you please explain what do you mean with "dropped first to make room - everything else would just move up"?

Comment: This could be resolved with something called "Object Pooling". Imagine a game like Flappy Bird or Galaga -- they clearly need to make new objects constantly. So, how do they do it without running up a memory bill that makes Google Chrome blush? By building a pool object with a limited number of instances, and re-allocating the previous instances to new locations when they are needed. Here is a [detailed tutorial on Object Pooling](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/introduction-to-object-pooling).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have any code to offer, just ideas that you would have to implement yourself.

I think the Data Structure you need is something similar [to a Queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type)) with Size limit: You add all new Cubes with Enqueue. If you exceed the size target during Enqueue, you Dequeue (and then remove from the scene) whatever is exceeding the limit.

Unfortunately I doubt you can use any of the existing Queue implementations like [Queue[T]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1?view=net-5.0) - at least not without overriding or hiding the Enqueue function with your own implementation - as they are not designed to enforce a limit. Much less enforce it by Dequeue-ing excess and running some Unity on code on whatever it Dequeues that way.

Comment: I was referred in a comment above to object pooling, which actually turned out to also require a queue. Therefore, at least in my case, both have to be used together.

Comment: @Omar The goal of both is to either scrap or recycle the "oldest" object first. And a First-In, First-Out collection is the tool for that either way. The Queue is only there to help to give you a clear, unambigious order.